# Uniqueness of measures related to the Stieltjes transforms

Tags: measure-theory, moment-problem

Suppose that $\mu$ is a Radon measure on $\mathbb{R}$, and let $I(\mu)$ be the Stieltjes transform of $\mu$, i.e. $I(\mu)(\lambda)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{x-\lambda}\,\mathrm{d}\mu(x)$ for $\lambda$ non-real. If $I(\mu)(\lambda)$ happens to be equal to zero, would it imply that $\mu=0$? If yes, why? I can't find any theorem stating about it, so I ask for your help. Maybe it has something with injectivity to do with?

Comment: Equal to $0$ for some particular $\lambda$ or for all $\lambda\in\mathbb C\setminus \mathbb R$?

Comment: In https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/matrix-book.pdf, p.171, It is stated that the imaginary part of $I(\mu)$ can be expressed as a convolution of $\mu$ with the Poisson kernel. That will show uniqueness if the transform in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in an earlier comment, The imaginary part of the Stieltjes transform $I_\mu$ (in your notation) is $\pi P*\mu$, where $P$ is the Poisson kernel.

A short but concise presentation if the Stieltjes integral in Barry Simon's Comprehensive Course in Analysis, Volume 3 (Harmonic Analysis) section 2.5. Amongst all the different cool things one can find there is the following Theorem:

**Theorem:**
Let $\mu$ be a finite measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and $F_\mu(z)=\int\frac{\mu(dx)}{x-z}$ be its Stieltjes transform. Suppose
$$ \mu(dx) = f\cdot\lambda(dx) + \mu_s(dx)$$
be its Lebesgue decomposition (absolute and singular decomposition with respect the LEbeshue measure $\lambda$. Then

a. $\frac{1}{\pi}\int \operatorname{Im}\,F_\mu(x+ i\varepsilon)g(x)\,dx \xrightarrow{\varepsilon\rightarrow0+}\int g(x)\mu(dx)$ for any $g\in \mathcal{C}_{00}(\mathbb{R})$ (functions of compact support).

b. For $\lambda$-a.a. $x\in \mathbb{R}$,
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0+}\operatorname{Im} F_\mu(x+i\varepsilon)= f(x)$$

c. There exists a measurable set $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lambda(E)=0=\mu_s(\mathbb{R}\setminus E)$ such that
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0+}\operatorname{Im} F_\mu(x+i\varepsilon)= \infty,\qquad x\in E
$$

d. For all $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$,

$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0+}\varepsilon\operatorname{Im} F_\mu(x_0+i\varepsilon)= \mu(\{x_0\})
$$

---

I hope this helps answer your question, or  at least provides you with good reference that discusses interesting results and historical notes about the Stieltjes transform.

---

Comment: Wow, thanks for the info! When assuming that $F_{\mu}(z)=0$ for all $z$, would the point (d) imply that $\mu(\{x_0\})=0$? If so, how to conclude from here that $\mu=0$? I was thinking something like letting $B$ be any Borel set, and write $B=\bigcup_{x_0\in B}\{x_0\}$, but I fail to verify that $\mu(B)=0$.

Comment: If your measure $\mu$ is absolutely continuous to begin with, for instance, of $\mu(dx)=e^{-x^2}dx$, then you already know that $\mu(\{x_0\})=0$ for any point $x_0$. So (d) does not give you anything surpisingthere. But if $F_\mu\equiv0$, (a) tells you that when you integrate any continuous function of compact support against $\mu$ you get $0$, that means that the measure $\mu$ must be the zero measure.

Comment: OK, sorry for slow-learning. Needed to understand it completely. If $F_\mu\equiv 0$, then we get by (a) that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)\mathrm{d}\mu(x)=0$ for any continuous $g$ with compact support. Then, by the Riesz Representation theorem, there can be exactly one such $\mu$, namely $\mu=0$. Is that it?

Comment: @James: Yes, that is it. So no two pair of distinct finite measures on $\mathbb{R}$ have the same Stieltjes transform. Part b is also a neat result, for it says that if you have a measure $\mu$ with a density, then you can recover the density from the Stieltjes transform too. In  a sense, it works similarly to the Fourier transform.

Comment: Don't know how to thank you enough. Thanks for your help and lots of patience!

Comment: The pleasure is mine. I got to open an read for the first time Volume 3 of the latest Barry Simon saga.